# Double (Multi-level) Countdown in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Okay, so this is driving me nuts.

I am trying to make a countdown that counts to a certain day of the week in a certain timezone... and once the timer hits zero then it changes the countdown timer's caption and counts down to another day of the week in a different timezone.

Basically, I need it to show when Saturday starts in a certain timezone... and when it's Saturday I need it to count down to when Sunday starts in a different timezone...

***The idea is the two time-zones are the earliest and latest time-zones on either side of the international date line...*** so "it's Saturday somewhere for n more days/hours/minutes/seconds" vs. "it will be Saturday somewhere in n days/hours/minutes/seconds" -- it's actually "Saturday somewhere" for 50 hours.

I believe it's between 3am Friday and 5am Sunday in my timezone, so that is the border of "it's Saturday somewhere" -- this doesn't account for changes from daylight savings time.

Another issue is that people viewing the countdown timer won't all be in my timezone... so I'm thinking I might need to set it up to do a little math with the time-zone offset.

I feel like I'm over-thinking this. I've knit-picked my code to death and I just want to have a clean slate to hash this out from scratch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check Date.UTC method to get date-time according to the UTC timezone. Once you have the standarized date-time value, you can do your calculations.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have right now?

Comment: I made a pen of my current code... which doesn't work and is a cluster-f*ck of a mess... https://codepen.io/RageQuitKitty/pen/ReNymN

Comment: The timezones I'm trying to check are UTC-12 (AoE) and UTC+14 (LINT) So I need to know if it's Saturday in either of those time zones, and how long is left in Saturday in LINT -- and when it's not Saturday in either one of those time zones, I need to know how long until the next time it's Saturday in AoE.

Comment: You said vanilla, but this would be a lot less aggravating with Moment.js. Anyway... here's a thought. Saturday, Jan 03, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT had a timestamp of 172800000 (milliseconds). So the range of the first Saturday between GMT-12 to GMT+14 was 129600000 ms to 223200000. One week is 604800000 ms. Divide the current timestamp in milliseconds by one week, throw out the whole number and keep the remainder, then multiply the remainder back by the number of milliseconds in a week. If it falls between those two numbers, it should be a Saturday somewhere. (Though I haven't tried it).

Comment: Thanks joshstrike, I'll give that a try. 

Comment: I just realized there are a couple problems with my response. GMT-12 should be at the higher end since Saturday there starts 12 hours AFTER it starts in GMT. And 24 hours need to be added to it since Saturday then lasts a full day there. So... the range should be 122400000 (original Saturday 14 hours before it hit Saturday GMT) to 302400000 (original Saturday GMT, plus 12 hours, plus 24 hours).

Comment: I just did the math, and what I basically need to check is if it's between Fri 10am UTC and Sun 11:59am UTC. I feel like that simplifies it, at least a little...

Comment: Gonna post some code below, I think it works... at least, the end of it works...

Answer (score 0):

Per comments above, here's what I came up with... trying to keep it clear what's actually happening... (Edit: corrected...)

```
var currentTime = new Date().valueOf();
var wktime = currentTime/604800000;
wktime -= Math.floor(wktime);
wktime *= 604800000;
wktime -= 122400000;//milliseconds from zero time to the original saturday, so 0 is the start of saturday.
var lengthOfSaturday = (24+12+14)*60*60*1000; //just to make the math clear
if (wktime > lengthOfSaturday) {
  var msToNextSaturday = wktime-lengthOfSaturday;
} else {
  var timeLeftSaturday = lengthOfSaturday-wktime;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort.

Comment: I found another solution I might be able to adapt to what I need...

https://vincoding.com/weekly-repeating-countdown-timer-javascript/

I would just need to make this accept a second set of values and check if the current date/time is between the two or not before determining which date to countdown to...